# throw new ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK(callback);

Tags: node.js

I am using Node.js v17.1.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nx5jv.png)

And getting this error :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIEAT.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation on fs callback api](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsappendfilepath-data-options-callback), and the error message you are getting, you need to pass a callback to the appendFile function as it expects one as the last parameter:

```
   fs.appendFile('greeting.txt', `Hello ${user.username} !`, (err) => {
       if (err) throw err;
       console.log('The data was appended to greeting.txt!');
    });
```

Comment: awesome, consider marking this as the excepted answer if it helped